# Пауза и запуск асинхронной задачи

Tags: c#, task

Есть программа winforms имитирующая работу светофора. Пользователь задает интервал смены сигналов светофора, а так же может изменять цвет каждого фонаря с помощью компонента colorDialog. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку "Изменить цвет", поток отвечающий за смену сигналов приостанавливался(!не завершался!), до тех пор пока пользователь не выберет цвет из соответствующего компонента. Я пытался отслеживать поток по айдишнику и приостанавливать а затем запускать его в обработчике события на кнопке, но у меня ничего не получилось. Какие есть варианты решения данной проблемы?

Кнопка отвечающая за смену цвета

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //в этом месте нужно поставить поток на паузу
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            red = colorDialog1.Color;
        }
        //в этом месте нужно возобновить его выполнение
    }
```

И непосредственно метод для смены цветов:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var white = Color.White;

        int red_time = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value) * 1000;
        int yellow_time = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value) * 1000;
        int green_time = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value) * 1000;

        Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            soundPlayer.Play();

            taskId = Task.CurrentId;
            while (true)
            {
                red_light.BackColor = white;
                yellow_light.BackColor = white;
                await Task.Delay(green_time);
                soundPlayer.Stop();
                yellow_light.BackColor = yellow;
                await Task.Delay(yellow_time);
                red_light.BackColor = red;
                yellow_light.BackColor = white;
                green_light.BackColor = white;
                await Task.Delay(red_time);
                yellow_light.BackColor = yellow;
                await Task.Delay(yellow_time);
                green_light.BackColor = green;
                yellow_light.BackColor = white;
                red_light.BackColor = white;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Что то у вас все смешалось. Вам приостановить выполнение внутри асинхронной задачи до сигнала? AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEventSlim  или их async варианты, чтобы никакие потоки не задерживать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с помощью `CancellationTokenSource`

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startButton.Enabled = false;
    stopButton.Enabled = true;
    await RunColors();
    startButton.Enabled = true;
    stopButton.Enabled = false;
}

private async Task RunColors()
{
    try
    {
        var white = Color.White;

        int red_time = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value) * 1000;
        int yellow_time = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value) * 1000;
        int green_time = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value) * 1000;

        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            soundPlayer.Play();

            while (true)
            {
                red_light.BackColor = white;
                yellow_light.BackColor = white;
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(green_time, _cts.Token);
                }
                finally
                {
                    soundPlayer.Stop();
                }
                yellow_light.BackColor = yellow;
                await Task.Delay(yellow_time, _cts.Token);
                red_light.BackColor = red;
                yellow_light.BackColor = white;
                green_light.BackColor = white;
                await Task.Delay(red_time, _cts.Token);
                yellow_light.BackColor = yellow;
                await Task.Delay(yellow_time, _cts.Token);
                green_light.BackColor = green;
                yellow_light.BackColor = white;
                red_light.BackColor = white;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    _cts = null;
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Здесь конечно цикл завершается, но вы можете переделать логику так, как вам нужно, используя предложенную методику.

Чтобы мигалка перезапускалась с того же самого места, на котором была завершена, можно использовать шаблон программирования Конечный автомат.

Например завести переменную состояния

```cs
private int state;
```

И менять состояние в цикле

```cs
while (true)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0:
            red_light.BackColor = white;
            yellow_light.BackColor = white;
            state++;
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(green_time, _cts.Token);
            }
            finally
            {
                soundPlayer.Stop();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            yellow_light.BackColor = yellow;
            state++;
            await Task.Delay(yellow_time, _cts.Token);
            break;
        case 2:
            red_light.BackColor = red;
            yellow_light.BackColor = white;
            green_light.BackColor = white;
            state++;
            await Task.Delay(red_time, _cts.Token);
            break;
        case 3:
            yellow_light.BackColor = yellow;
            state++;
            await Task.Delay(yellow_time, _cts.Token);
            break;
        default:
            green_light.BackColor = green;
            yellow_light.BackColor = white;
            red_light.BackColor = white;
            state = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

После остановки токеном и перезапуска цикла, он вернется в то состояние, в котором находился до остановки.